Python Selenium Function Runs with tkinter Messagebox but Raises Exception on Its Own
I am writing a python script that can automate fetching of content from page. One function is this:
def extract_prices(elements, wait):
    parent_element = None
    child_element = None
    prices = []
    for element in elements:
        parent_element = element
        child_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, f"[style='color: rgb(44, 44, 45);']")))
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(child_element))
        child_element = parent_element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f"[style='color: rgb(44, 44, 45);']") # line 1
        price = child_element.get_attribute("innerHTML")
        util.alert(f"{element}, {price}") # line 2
        prices.append(price)
    return prices

Line 1 will always raise StaleElementReferenceException if I comment line 2.  However, if I leave line 2 as it is now, the function will run perfectly. I'm 100% sure that

the query ((By.CSS_SELECTOR, f"[style='color: rgb(44, 44, 45);']")) is valid, because at some time before this was working perfectly, I can't recall what did I changed; and
the DOM hasn't changed because I tried replacing the wait.until() with time.sleep(20), which should be more than sufficient for the webpage to stablise, but the issue persist.

I tried quite a lot solutions from ChatGPT but none succeeded, and I don't really know how to google my issue because I can't even describe it in a short query.
FYI, the util.alert() is here:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
def alert(msg, title="Alert"):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()  
    messagebox.showinfo(title, msg)

I also tried replacing line 2 with time.sleep(1) but the exception is still being raised. I was suspecting that the dialog window provided time for the webpage to stabilise, but it seems like my theory is wrong.
Thank you in advance!
